# App or extension that creates a time delay for visiting distracting sites?

Tags: productivity

There are many desktop apps and browser extensions that block access to distracting sites, either at all times or during certain times, or that limit access to such sites to no more than some number of minutes or hours per day. I'm looking for something slightly different: instead of blocking a site, the app or extension would *defer* access to it, by enforcing a delay between the time the user requests to access the site and the time access is granted. As an example, let's say I'm feeling low on willpower and succumb to the temptation to check the Reddit news feed. So I enter 'reddit.com' on the browser, but instead of seeing the site, I see a sign indicating that I'll be able to visit it in (say) 10 minutes, at which time the site becomes available for browsing. The idea is that these delays will help me avoid procrastinating, by moving the rewards beyond the "[akrasia horizon](http://blog.beeminder.com/flexbind/)". Does anyone know of an app or extension that offers this functionality? I use Chrome on a Mac, though I'm prepared to switch to Firefox if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Leechblock NG](https://www.proginosko.com/leechblock/) offers to define list of sites that will be delayed.

Delay time is configurable.

Block schedule is available (it may be 24/7, it may be on specific hours or days of week).

Available filters include domains, word in url - with possibility of wildcards, exceptions to filters configured in the same way.

How it works:

[image: example]